# Feasiable algorithm to list days of months as dropdown in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, dictionary, linkedhashmap

I have two dropdownlist,one indicates month and another indicates days.

My month dropdown list is as follows,

```
public Map<Integer, String> month(){

    final Map<Integer, String> month = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    month.put(4,"April");
    month.put(5,"May");
    month.put(6,"June");
    month.put(7,"July");
    month.put(8,"August");
    month.put(9, "September");
    month.put(10,"October");
    month.put(11,"November");
    month.put(12,"December");
    month.put(1, "January");
    month.put(2,"February");
    month.put(3, "March");

 return monthmap;
}
```

for days the map is like

```
  public Map<Integer, Integer> dayOfMonth(){

            Map<Integer, Integer> day = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
//In this section feasible algorithm required.
            for(int i=1;i<32;i++)
            {
                day.put(i,i);
            }

          return day;
        }
```

Based on this algorithm i got for every month with 31 days.But i need only correct days for corresponding months.For ex:"june needs only 30 days,in this case it have 31 days".So what i need is that based on the month map,all corresponding days should be inserted inside the day map.

For example`[(4,(1 to 30)),(5,(1 to 31)` and so on upto march].`

I am using core java for these section code.For ui part jquery and javascript are used.Spring MVC is the technology used.I am struggling for the entire day to get a fesiable solution.Any help will be highly appreciable .....

Comment: why you not calculate the #days in the month ?

Comment: based on my requirement i just need to add to day(my list) as key value pair as indicated in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to care about leap years and others... So create a `Calendar`, set `year` and `month` and use [`getActualMaximum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int)) to don't need to reinvent the weel.

```
int iYear = 2016;
int iMonth = Calendar.FEBRUARY;
int iDay = 1;

// Calendar object and set year and month
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(iYear, iMonth, iDay);

// Number of days in that month
int daysInMonth = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // 29 !!!
```

**ADD ONS:**

- After this, just use `daysInMonth + 1` in your actual `for-loop`.

  ```
  for(int i=1; i < daysInMonth + 1; i++)
  ```
- Of course, better create a function to encapsulate and replace 2 line

  ```
  private int getNumberOfDays(int month, int year) {
      Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
      return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // 29 !!!
  }
  ```

  And call it like: `getNumberOfDays(Calendar.FEBRUARY, 2016);`.

Comment: Actually i have two dropdownlists,one for indicating month and another for day.My drop down list will be same throughout the years.No need to change it for the next year and so on.Actually it is to represent a season for a school.

Comment: In 2016, February will have 29 days, you **MUST** represent this in your app if you want to mantain a minimum quality... And as you can see, method getting the days are 2 lines of code, much better than a Map with 12 fixed values for each month.... don't you think?

Comment: remember!  **Don't hesitate to ask** if you have any doubt or issue . :)

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. The [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) knows the number of days in each month.

```
int daysInApril = Month.APRIL.maxLength();
int currentMonthLength = LocalDate.now().getMonth().maxLength();
```

If you need days for current year, get date instance with [`LocalDate.now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) and use their simple [`plusMonths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-) and [`minusMonths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusMonths-long-) methods until you have collected all months for the year. Then just get the days for those months using same API.

Comment: You may want to omit February 29th for non-[Leap years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year). Ask the [`Year`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class if a particular year is a Leap year or not.  `Year.of( 2015 ).isLeap()` …or… `Year.from( myLocalDate ).isLeap()`

Answer (score -1):

See Calendar#getActualMaximum: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int)

It will allow you to find how many days are in each month.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2100);

    System.out.println(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); // 28, not 29
}
```

@Arun nagar your code is broken and won't work for eg. the year 2100 (dividable by 4 but NOT a leap year). I can't downvote because I don't have enough reputation, but I would

Comment: hi @spi, I would recommend you to provide some example code with the links, this will help OP and you will get better feedback from other users